# How to pass list of objects in json object

Tags: json, arraylist, arrays

Hi I am developing small application in which I am trying to pass some data in http post method. So I want to send my data like this form

```
"storeid": "151",
    "floordata": {
    "entry": [
        10,
        15
    ],
    "exit": [
        10,
        15
    ],

    "section": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "sectionname": "ABC",
            "category": "office",
           "boundary": [
                [
                    85,
                    258
                ],
                [
                    85,
                    298
                ],
                [
                    125,
                    298
                ],
                [
                    125,
                    258
                ],
                [
                    85,
                    258
                ]
            "description": "Mobile based company"
        }
    ]
    },
    "category": null,
    "description": null
```

so my problem is regarding section parameter. I am doing this for section parameter.

```
        String section = "section=";

        // Problem for me is here ... 
        JSONArray sections = new JSONArray();

        List<List<Float>> sectionCords = new ArrayList<List<Float>>();
        List<Float> sectionCordData = new ArrayList<Float>();
        sectionCordData.add(0.0f);
        sectionCordData.add(0.1f);

        List<Float> sectionCordData1 = new ArrayList<Float>();
        sectionCordData1.add(0.0f);
        sectionCordData1.add(0.1f);

        sectionCords.add(sectionCordData);
        sectionCords.add(sectionCordData1);

        JSONObject sectionObj = new JSONObject();
        //List<JSONObject> cordList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();

        try {
            sectionObj.put("category", "office");
            sectionObj.put("description", "Mobile based company");
            sectionObj.put("sectionname", "mobiotics");
            sectionObj.put("id", 0);
            sectionObj.put("boundary", sectionCords); // Check Here i am sending as list ...

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sections.put(sectionObj);
        section += sections;

        section +="&";
```

But In actual it my section boundary parameter going as string instead of list. Like this

```
 boundary=[
  [
    0.0,
    0.1
  ],
  [
    0.0,
    0.1
  ]
],storeid=156&floor=2&section=[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "sectionname": "mobiotics",
    "category": "office",
    "boundary": "[[0.0, 0.1], [0.0, 0.1]]", // See here is my problem ...
    "description": "Mobile based company"
  }
],entry=[
  10,
  15
],exit=[
  10,
  15
]
```

How to send it as list instead of string. Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define `sectionChords`, and `sectionCordData`* as JSONArray instead of List:

```
JSONArray sectionChords = new JSONArray();
    JSONArray sectionCordData = new JSONArray();
    sectionCordData.put(0.0f);
    sectionCordData.put(0.1f);

    JSONArray sectionCordData1 = new JSONArray();
    sectionCordData1.put(0.0f);
    sectionCordData1.put(0.1f);

    sectionCords.put(sectionCordData);
    sectionCords.put(sectionCordData1);
```

Comment: Awesome buddy. But can you please explain me why this so ?

Comment: It should be able to produce array (just like you intended to) according to API: JSONObject.put(java.lang.String key, java.util.Collection value). However, looks like the library you are using fails to do it with nested collection. You are able to do it with custom class instead of inner list.

Comment: @nilkash Btw, http://jettison.codehaus.org/ is able to do marshalling right using your code

Answer (score 1):

It must do what you want according to [docs](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

> Put a key/value pair in the JSONObject, where the value will be a JSONArray which is produced from a Collection.

But it puts JSON representation of your object as *String*. So you should use either JSONArrays or Java objects. You should not mix them.

Answer (score 0):

controller :

```
 public JsonResult Index()
        {
            List<Location> location = (from a in db.Locations select a).ToList();
            return Json(location, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```